# Electric field formula in Second-Harmonic Generation

Tags: non-linear-optics

When Second Harmonic-Generation is presented, the formula for the electric field is $E(t)=E_0 e^{i\omega t}+E_0^{*} e^{-i\omega t}$, where $^*$ represents complex conjugation. Is there a physical reason why we have to consider both terms $E_0 e^{i\omega t}$ and $E_0^{*} e^{-i\omega t}$? Why can't we use only $E(t)=E_0 e^{i\omega t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual electric field is real, so a monochromatic oscillation must be represented by $E_{0}e^{i\omega t}$ plus its complex conjugate.  Depending on the application, the counter-rotating field with the $e^{-i\omega t}$ might or might not be relevant.  In a magnetic resonance experiment, the co-rotating ($e^{i\omega t}$) wave is responsible for the resonance phenomena; however, the counter-rotating wave is responsible for an additional small (but observable) energy shift, known as the Bloch-Siegert shift.

In a nonlinear optics experiment, which of the co-rotating and counter-rotating waves is important depends on the precise nature of the effect.  However, a typical second harmonic generation system will produce new fields of the form $E_{0}'e^{2i\omega t}+E_{0}'^{*}e^{-2i\omega t}$, with $E_{0}'\propto (E_{0})^{2}$.  This is necessary, since the final field must also be real.  And again, the application will determine whether the $e^{-2i\omega t}$ field is of any practical importance.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a real harmonic function you add the complex conjugate to the complex exponential function so that the imaginary parts cancel out: $$E(t)=E_0 e^{i\omega t}+E_0^{*} e^{-i\omega t}= |E_0| [\cos{(\omega t+\phi)}+i\sin{(\omega t}+\phi)+\cos{(\omega t+\phi)}-i\sin{(\omega t+\phi})]=2|E_0|\cos{(\omega t+\phi)}$$ where $E_0=|E_0|e^{i\phi}$.